# what is the equivalent converted vb.net code for following c# code

Tags: vb.net, stripe.net

I have tried various code converters but it is giving me error while running the application.

```
myCustomer.Card = new StripeCreditCardOptions() { TokenId = token };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myCustomer.Card = New StripeCreditCardOptions() With { .TokenId = token }
```